# Can state preservation and restoration in CoreBluetooth work when bluetooth is powered off

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on an app that implements the central role. I have added support for state preservation and restoration in my app, but this feature does not work when my app was terminated by system either after the bluetooth had been powered off or the bluetooth would be powered off later.

Is it possible to use this feature when the bluetooth is powered off?
If not, is there any document or video that can tell me why from Apple?
If possible, is there anyone who can tell me how?